# A web page where users can submit feedback stored in a db

Tags: mysql

Im creating a web page where user can submit feedback. These feedback will be stored in a mysql db on the server. Im using PHP, do I have an open user account in the db that is allowed to only insert to the specified table? Im confused since the password is in the open in submit form, or am i misunderstanding something?

```
$db_password = 'password';
```

this is accessible to anyone isnt it? Should i encrypt it somehow in the form?

Comment: Can you post your html and the rest of your code? Does the user need to login to send feedack? Can you explain the logical flow of the process a little bit better as for it is unclear to me.

Comment: no, no login, its just a feedback form with some inputs. I dont have any code yet for that part yet, but i have set up my db etc on the server. So I only want to insert some fields into a table on my server from my website to process later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example:

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Add Record Form</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="insert.php" method="post">
    <p>
        <label for="firstName">First Name:</label>
        <input type="text" name="firstname" id="firstName">
    </p>
    <p>
        <label for="lastName">Last Name:</label>
        <input type="text" name="lastname" id="lastName">
    </p>
    <p>
        <label for="emailAddress">Email Address:</label>
        <input type="text" name="email" id="emailAddress">
    </p>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

**PHP**

```
<?php
/* Attempt MySQL server connection. 
server with default setting (user 'root' with no password) */
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "demo");

// Check connection
if($link === false){
    die("ERROR: Could not connect. " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

// Escape user inputs for security
$first_name = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['firstname']);
$last_name = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['lastname']);
$email_address = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['email']);

// attempt insert query execution
$sql = "INSERT INTO persons (first_name, last_name, email_address) VALUES ('$first_name', '$last_name', '$email_address')";
if(mysqli_query($link, $sql)){
    echo "Records added successfully.";
} else{
    echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql. " . mysqli_error($link);
}

// close connection
mysqli_close($link);
?>
```

Okay so that will insert the posted data on the form, what you need for the table and the database permissions is only to create a new user (your custom user) and then assign read and write permissions to this user assuming you are going to read the data at some point. Then as in the above php example replace your **mysql user**  with **'root'** if you specified a password just add it next to root in the empty string. To answer the password that is accessible to anyone, the answer is no. PHP is a server side scripting language everything is rendered and validated on the server and only the markup is sent to the client, unless you deliberately send the db password to the client.